# Constructor inheritance with classes of the same name

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, using, constructor-inheritance

I want to inherit the constructor of the base class, but don't compile.
How can I solve this problem without changing the class name?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    class A
    {

    };
};

class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
public:
    class A : MyClass::A
    {
        //error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘namespace’
        using (MyClass::A)::(MyClass::A);
    };
};
```

Comment: @uneven_mark thanks problem solved =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using MyClass::A::A;
```

The constructor is referred to by a qualified name to the base class from which it should be imported, i.e. `MyClass::A`, and then again the class name to refer to the constructor, but only the class name, not a qualified name, i.e. `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Does using `MyClass::A::A;` do what you want?

If you want to use `method()` from class `MyClass::A`, you have to write `using MyClass::A::method;`. In your case, `method()` is the constructor, named `A()`.